# Подсчитать заполненные поля в БД php

Tags: php, база-данных, count

Здравствуйте,ситуация следующая, имеется таблица со столбцами id и link в таблице links, в столбце id все ячейки пронумерованы(1-30), а в link не все поля ячейки заняты, задача состоит в том, что бы подсчитать заполненные поля.

Испробовал кучу запросов `COUNT(*)` и ему подобных,в основном,если и работает скрипт,то отображает цифру 1(а записей у меня там 3). Я так понимаю 1 - это что то вроде сигнала ошибки. Помогите пожалуйста.

Заранее спасибо всем.

Comment: SELECT link FROM table WHERE link != NULL (или значению по умолчанию в виде пустой строки), сколько строк вернет подсчитать не трудно думаю, хотя способ возможно с родни костылю, не знаю.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стратегия подсчета заполненных полей link зависит от того, что находится в пустых полях. Если в пустых полях link находится значение NULL, достаточно воспользоваться запросом

```
SELECT COUNT(link) FROM links
```

Агрегатная функция COUNT() подсчитывает только не NULL-значения.

Если в пустых полях link находится пустая строка, то можно дополнить запрос WHERE-условием, которое проверит не равно ли значение link пустой строке.

```
SELECT COUNT(link) FROM links WHERE link <> ''
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо,мучился долго,думал что не так,а тот оказывается вот что,пустые кавычки нужны)

Answer (score 0):

Если значение по умолчанию для LINK = NULL, то количество записей, где этот столбец заполнен должен вернуть вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS count FROM links WHERE link IS NOT NULL;
```

Если же значение по умолчанию - "" - то запрос будет таким:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS count FROM links WHERE link <> '';
```